# Console messages "warning: we're on the slow path" from syncdefaultsd

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, console

My MacBook (Mid-2010 model) has been sluggish lately and so I decided to check the console to see what was going on. Here is what I found, multiple times:

4/15/14 9:52:55.488 PM syncdefaultsd[20962]: -[IAPluginManager allAListPlugins] [546] -- *** warning: we're on the slow path.

Any idea on what this might be related to?

Comment: Are there any kernel messages relating to I/O errors?

Comment: I don't see any I/O errors.